# Win 10 user folder access

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts

I have 2 PCs with Windows 10. I need to move the HDD of pc A to pc B, then add to user B all the permissions to use that disk as it it was user A.

User A is my administrator and only account on pc A, user B is my administrator and only account on pc B.

I do not want to take ownership, I need to put that disk again in PC A, I want user B to act as A, forever.

How can I do this? Is there a way to copy, clone or export those permissions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On both PCs add the users as members to the built-in group `Replicator`, then assign the required permissions to the `Replicator` group.

Because it is a built-in group, all permissions are valid under any Windows installation on any Windows PC.

Both users are already members of the built-in group `Administrators` but because of UAC that doesn't have any effect on file permissions when using Windows File Explorer.